# Using mysql connectivity in Spring boot with gradle via JPA and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Using mysql connectivity in Spring boot with gradle via JPA and hibernate. Using mysql 8 version.

While connecting mysql via spring boot jpa i'm getting following exception

[image]

I have added everything in gradle and property file.
Following is my application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
server.port=8081
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tes?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

This is my build gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
 baseName = 'boot-gradle'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web','org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
,'javax.servlet:jstl')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("com.h2database:h2")
compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tes?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false ...Is it tes or test?

Comment: no no it is tes only

Comment: spring.datasource.test-on-borrow= true .....try adding this line and check once.

Comment: same error after adding this property too.

Comment: *ISSUE RESOLVED* - The issue is compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java") in build.gradle adds 5.*.* jar to the library but i'm using mysql-8. So add the version 8 of mysql-connector jar. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your gradle file is not correct , here is a sample code to connect to mysql in spring using JPA

sql file

```
drop database if exists AppleDb;
create database AppleDb; 
use AppleDb;
create table apple (apple_id bigint not null, apple_name varchar(255), primary key (apple_id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB;
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 );
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("Macintosh", 1);
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("Fuji", 2);
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("Gala", 3);
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("Jonagold", 4);
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("GrannySmith", 5);
insert into apple (apple_name, apple_id) values ("PinkLady", 6);
```

controller

```
package com.sujan.example.jpa.controller;

import com.sujan.example.jpa.entity.Apple;
import com.sujan.example.jpa.repository.AppleRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class AppleController {
    @Autowired
    private AppleRepository appleRepository;

    @GetMapping
    List<Apple> findAll() {
        List<Apple> findAll = appleRepository.findAll();
        findAll.forEach(System.out::println);
        return findAll;
    }
}
```

entity

```
package com.sujan.example.jpa.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Apple {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long appleId;
    private String appleName;

    public Apple(String appleName) {
        this.appleName = appleName;
    }
}
```

repository

```
package com.sujan.example.jpa.repository;

import com.sujan.example.jpa.entity.Apple;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AppleRepository extends JpaRepository<Apple, Long> {
}
```

main class

```
package com.sujan.example.jpa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AppleDb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

gradle.properties

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
group = 'com.sujan'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/'
```